# Replace strings in a long String:

Tags: java, android, string, indexof

I have the following string:

> Where Are You [Employee Name]?
>   your have a [Shift] shift...

and a list of strings that contains:

**1.** Employee Name

**2.** Shift

I need to find the given strings in the list in the long string and replace them with another content (including the `[` and `]` characters).
So for example the first string is need to be change to:

> Where Are You Jhon Green?
>   your have a morning shift...

Is there any simple way to do that? using `IndexOf` will give me the location of this string but how would I include the `[` , `]` charecters as well?

**UPDATE:**
This is the code I tested so far:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(smsText);

    for (String s; (s = sc.findWithinHorizon("(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])", 0)) != null;) 
    {
         words.add(s);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); j++)  
    {  
        Log.d(TAG, "The value for column: "+words.get(j) +" is: "+ rowData.getValue(words.get(j)));
        smsText.replaceFirst("\\[" + words.get(j) + "\\]", rowData.getValue(words.get(j)));
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Final String is: "+ smsText);
```

which is not giving me the right result, the string are not replaced.

**UPDATE2:**
The solution that worked for me is:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(smsText);

    for (String s; (s = sc.findWithinHorizon("(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])", 0)) != null;) 
    {
         columnNames.add(s);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.size(); j++)  
    {  
        Log.d(TAG, "The value for column: "+columnNames.get(j) +" is: "+ rowData.getValue(columnNames.get(j)));
        smsText = smsText.replaceFirst("\\[" + columnNames.get(j) + "\\]", rowData.getValue(columnNames.get(j)));
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Final String is: "+ smsText);
```

Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: If you have control over the template, switch them to `%s` and use `String.format()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, unfortunately I don't, what more the phrase inside the "[" and "]" is a column name from which I need to extract the replaced content so it can't be changed either.

Comment: @EmilAdz is this string `Where Are You [Employee Name]? your have a [Shift] shift` common? and do you want to replace `[Employee Name]` with name of the employee right? let me know

Comment: The string as  a whole as well as the Employee Name string are dynamic and could be changed from server side.

Comment: What result is it giving you? What result do you want?

Comment: if you like to have recursive function for that check my answer

Comment: You need to save your result from the replaceFirst: `smsText = smsText.replaceFirst(...`

Comment: @EmilAdz check my recursive function in the answers. it is working for all cases

Comment: @ShafqatMasood, thanks for you answer. +1 for your effort. But I do wan't to avoid recursive solutions.

Comment: @Keppil, thanks for the note, of saving the string this what solved my issue. with the solution given by nullptr. +1 for your answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String key = myColumns.getName();
s.replaceFirst("\\[" + key + "\\]", myReplacements.getReplacement(key));
```

You could also use `indexOf`, but with a replace function it's immediately clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Employee Name and Shift are parameters that represent column names and will be changed (this is only a case example). So I need a more generic solution.

Comment: Thanks @nullptr, give me few mins to test it.

Comment: see updated question, this is not working for me for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    String s = "Where Are You [Employee Name]? your have a [Shift] shift..";
    Map<String, String> replacementMap = new HashMap<>();
    replacementMap.put("[Employee Name]", "John Green");
    replacementMap.put("[Shift]", "morning");
    for(Entry<String, String> e : replacementMap.entrySet()) {
        s = s.replace(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
Where Are You John Green? your have a morning shift..
```

Comment: I need to replace those strings, not to find them as in the previous question.

Comment: @EmilAdz it is easy to replace when you find them  Check this http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/18488

Answer (score 1):

A general solution could look something like this:

```
String message = "Where are you [Employee Name]? You have a [Shift] shift!";
Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<>();
variables.put("Employee Name", "John Green");
variables.put("Shift", "morning");
StringBuffer endResult = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]").matcher(message);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(endResult, variables.get(m.group(1)));
}
m.appendTail(endResult);
System.out.println(endResult.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

i know regex is there but if you want to go for recursive function here it is

```
   public string replaceString(string str, string[] values, int index)
    {
        if (str.IndexOf('[') == -1 || str.IndexOf(']') == -1 || index > values.Length-1)
            return str;
        else

            return replaceString(str.Replace(str.Substring(str.IndexOf('['), (str.IndexOf(']') - str.IndexOf('['))+1), values[index]), values, ++index);
    }
```

calling this method

```
     string strforreplac = "Where Are You [Employee Name]? your have a [Shift] shift...]";
           string[] strvalues = {"Emil","morning"};
      string newstring = replaceString(strforreplac,strvalues,0);
```